# How to effectively generate object in for or while

Tags: java, object, for-loop, while-loop

I have this kind of structure of program.

This program have one function named run(), and the other function named solve().

In this program, I want to get some information from run() and solve().
Also, I want to put these information to one list vector (named information_one_iteration in the following code).

Because this vectors get together to form a matrix (named information in the following code).

That's why I define the information_one_iteration as static variable, and in every new iteration new objects is defined newly.

But, I know this kind of way is not effective! 
How can I improve it?

```
package java_test2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class staticvarTest {

private Random random = new Random();

static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> information = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
static ArrayList<String> information_one_iteration = new ArrayList<String>();

public staticvarTest() {

}

public void run() {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        information_one_iteration.add(String.valueOf(i));
        solve(); // add two random number generated in function solve()
        information.add(information_one_iteration);

        information_one_iteration = new ArrayList<String>();


    }
    print_information(information);
}

public void solve() {

    information_one_iteration.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
    information_one_iteration.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
}

public static void print_information(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> information) {
    for (ArrayList<String> newLine : information) {
        ArrayList<String> list_set = newLine;
        System.out.println("");
        for(String data: list_set) {
            System.out.print(data+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    staticvarTest na = new staticvarTest();
    na.run();
}
}
```

Comment: When you say not effective, what do you mean? Can you elaborate a bit on what your expected output is for this question?

Comment: Also on a sidenote: Please stick to the naming conventions in Java. Makes it much easier for anyone else reading your code.

Comment: I think that I should assign null to object after using it. However when i use code above, I can't not assign null. That why i think it is not effective. Thanks your comment!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using `static ArrayList<String> information_one_iteration = new ArrayList<String>();` anywhere apart from the run method you can remove it.

I have changed the `random` variable since it's okay for multiple objects to share it - the behaviour remains the same therefore no need to initialize every time Main object is created.

Change the solve method to take a ArrayList as a parameter too.

print_information looks okay but there is no need for `ArrayList<String> list_set = newLine;`

I have also made `information` as a state variable over a static variable so that each instance of the object can have it's own information therefore allowing you to run multiple instances of this class.

I also added a lambda to print the members to give you an idea about them `newLine.forEach(data -> System.out.println(data + " "));`.

Finally I have used variable names and class names that adhere to Java coding conventions for better readability. Here is one of the style guides which you may follow https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

The cleaned up version of your code is below

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> information = new ArrayList<>();


    private void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            ArrayList<String> informationInIteration = new ArrayList<>();
            informationInIteration.add(String.valueOf(i));
            solve(informationInIteration); // add two random number generated in function solve()
            information.add(informationInIteration);
        }
        printInformation();
    }

    private void solve(ArrayList<String> iterationInformation) {
        iterationInformation.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
        iterationInformation.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
    }

    private void printInformation() {
        for (ArrayList<String> newLine : information) {
            System.out.println();
            newLine.forEach(data -> System.out.println(data + " "));
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }
}
```

Based on your comments I am adding a method that creates no object for storing any information.

package com.company;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private Random random = new Random();


    private void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
            System.out.println(random.nextInt() + " " + random.nextInt() + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prathik Rajendran M!! Actually, I really want to avoid making lots of object in computer memory. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have updated the answer with another approach that stores nothing, therefore doesn't make any objects and provides the same output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
public void run() {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        staticvarTest.information.add(solve(String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    print_information(information);
}

public String[] solve(String i) {
    return {String.valueOf(random.nextInt()), 
            String.valueOf(random.nextInt()),
            i};
}
```

Or you could maybe concatenate the array returned in solve() and the i String and avoid passing the variable around.

I have not tested the code above btw but apart from accessing and modifying the static variable there shouldn't be a problem.

Hope this works for you.